# How to Train LSTM across Multiple Time Series datasets

Tags: time-series, neural-networks, lstm, transfer-learning

I believe there are generalizable mapping rules that can be extracted from multiple time series data-sets I have. Each data-set represents a specific company, and while I am able to train on each company individually, I'm having trouble finding literature or conceptualizing how to train across all my datasets (which have multiple features and one output), to glean the generalized mapping of features to output instead of the individual mapping for each company.

I have looked into transfer learning, but that seems to simply be freezing of certain layers of the neural network while letting others train, but this method seems difficult to extend to the 4000+ companies/datasets I have.

If it matters, I am using keras with tensoflow backend, and all my time series data-sets are the same size.

Thanks for your thoughts.

Comment: I don't know how your data are organized, but couldn't you just write a routine in which it would train on a sequence from company A, reset the state, then train on a sequence from company B, reset the state, etc.? The parameters would evolve across training sequences but the state reset would keep the sequences from blending together.

Comment: Thanks Josh, before I go ahead and try that, what does resetting the state mean in the context of a neural network?

Comment: I'm referring to the internal state of each LSTM cell. This concept is fundamental to "gated" recurrent network cells like LSTMs and GRUs. If you're not familiar with it I'd definitely recommend familiarizing yourself before going any further. Start here: http://colah.github.io/posts/2015-08-Understanding-LSTMs/

Comment: On another note, this problem goes away completely if you do away with RNNs and just use a feedforward network. Then you can just combine all the companies' data into one dataset and train a single network. Of course, then you'd probably wind up having to do some feature engineering, but that might not be the worst thing either. I'm assuming that you have the same predictors/features for each company, is that right?

Comment: Yes, same predictors/features...but the output depends on the historical time series of the predictors/features, and not just that row/period's predictors/feature values...do you think I can do away with RNN and still maintain the ability to train from historical series of predictors?

Comment: Very likely, but you'll probably have to do some "feature engineering" to derive various transformations of those predictors (such as moving averages of different window lengths) so each row of data contains some of the information from prior rows. However, this is going to be a lot easier than designing an LSTM training routine like the one I described, especially if you're not very familiar with RNNs in general and LSTMs specifically.

Comment: Here is a possible solution to the problem, create a variable to define each company (like an id) and train all together: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/305863/how-to-train-lstm-model-on-multiple-time-series-data?newreg=4f8fb83b101540d48964a353e8c29273