# Model Architecture Multi-Agents

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, lstm

My question is based on a previews post:
[How to train LSTM model on multiple time series data?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/305863/how-to-train-lstm-model-on-multiple-time-series-data) .

The task is basically the same. However, my question builds on that: What does the model architecture look like for the Proposed Solution ? Does the agent_id have to be entered individually into the embedding layer and then linked to the other features, or are the other agent features also simply pushed into the embedding layer?  If someone has a code snippet that would be great!