# Shortening LSTM Sequences

Tags: neural-networks, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am training an LSTM where I have sales data from 20 different individuals over the past 10 years.

Now, I read this brilliant answer: [How to train LSTM model on multiple time series data?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/305863/how-to-train-lstm-model-on-multiple-time-series-data)

But, due to domain knowledge / prior analysis, I believe that only “recent” timesteps are useful in predicting a future timestep, let’s say, the previous 1 year.

Now, what do I do with all of this historical data? Do I just not use it?

Can I just create more subsequences out of these longer sequences and train the LSTM on these as well?

Or do I have to input the whole sequence for each individual?